# RPG.SE Chat Fudge dice: a userscript for Fate & Fudge games

Tags: script, chat, tampermonkey

[RPG.SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/)'s chat rooms support dice rolls as an easter egg. This script will convert **d6** rolls that you see into **Fudge dice**, using the ordinary conversion rules: 1–2 = minus, 3–4 = blank, 5–6 = plus.

You can enable or disable these dice on a per-room basis. It will remember which rooms you picked. You can play around with the script and our other dice in our [Dice roller & formatting tests](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16836/dice-roller-formatting-tests) chat room. To enable it for the first time, open the fudge dice menu in your chat sidebar and switch it on:

[image: the fudge dice link is after the 'leave (all)', 'room', and 'info' links.]

## Downloading / installation:

**[Download this script here!](https://github.com/scarletcs/rpgse-chat-fudge-dice/raw/main/src/index.user.js)**

You may also [view the source on github](https://github.com/scarletcs/rpgse-chat-fudge-dice/blob/main/src/index.user.js).

You will need a userscript manager such as Tampermonkey ([Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/), [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en)).

## What's it look like?

Behold, an ordinary 4d6 roll:

[image: 5, 2, 1, 3]

Converted to Fudge dice:

[image: plus, minus, minus, blank]

Optionally with customisable colours!

[image: red minuses, green pluses]

[image: blue minuses, purple pluses]

(This is `#cc00ff` for plus and `#0088ff` for minus)

Since the dice roller defaults to rolling 6-sided dice, the quickest way for Fate players to roll a dice set is to just type **4d**.

Your color scheme affects only dice you see. Others won't see your colour scheme, and people will only see fudge dice if they're running the script too.

### New in version 2

If you had a previous version, I screwed up its auto-update. Sorry! You'll need to hit the download link above.

Anyway, here's the new shiny stuff:

- **You can now switch fudge dice off without a page reload.** Previously the script destroyed all dots in sight, but now it just hides them. Go nuts hitting that “Use fudge dice here” toggle!
- The color sampler square is now a **color picker**. Or at least, I hope it is—your browser *ought* to support this. Click it to pick your color using your browser or system's UI!
- You can hover over a die to see what the actual d6 roll was without having to switch off the fudge dice display:
  [image: "Rolled 5"]

In terms of maintenance, the script has been rebuilt completely from the ground up to modernise it. I've dropped dependencies on jQuery, on deprecated web interfaces (like DOM change events), and on an external color picker that had vanished. Features that worked fine before work better now.